mypy function signature matching for **kwargs argument and different kinds of return types
I have a class that I am trying to make as an interface. For simplicity, I've only included one of the abstract methods (see below).
class MyInterface(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
    @classmethod
    def __subclasshook__(cls, subclass):
        return (hasattr(subclass, "do_stuff") and callable(subclass.do_stuff))

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def do_stuff(self, input: str, output: str, **kwargs) -> Union[str, list[str]]:
        raise NotImplementedError

In a subclasses that inherit this, I'd like the **kwargs to be an optional thing we can add. I also would like the return type to be either a string or list of strings not both, so four use cases
class ImpClass1(MyInterface):
    def do_stuff(self, input: str, output: str, **kwargs) -> str: ...

class ImpClass2(MyInterface):
    def do_stuff(self, input: str, output: str, **kwargs) -> list[str]: ...

class ImpClass3(MyInterface):
    def do_stuff(self, input: str, output: str) -> str: ...

class ImpClass4(MyInterface):
    def do_stuff(self, input: str, output: str) -> list[str]: ...

mypy throws an error currently when I use the third use case, so I assume the rest will fail similarly
src/tests/parser/test_interface.py:43: error: Signature of "do_stuff" incompatible with supertype "MyInterface"  [override]
src/tests/parser/test_interface.py:43: note:      Superclass:
src/tests/parser/test_interface.py:43: note:          def do_stuff(self, input: str, output: str, **kwargs: Any) -> Union[str, list[str]]
src/tests/parser/test_interface.py:43: note:      Subclass:
src/tests/parser/test_interface.py:43: note:          def do_stuff(self, input: str, output: str) -> str

How do I have mypy catch breaks of the signature but not for the cases that I've listed above?

If **kwargs is optional, then it should only present in the subclasses, not the parent class. Does that work for you? (I also took the liberty to fix some typos in the question; rollback or re-edit if you find my changes problematic.)

When overriding a base class method, the child class method should be able to invoked the same way that the base class method can be, otherwise an instance of the child class cannot safely be substituted with an instance of the base class. In the super class you allow arbitrary extra args to be defined. e.g. You can call obj.do_stuff("foo", "bar", some="value") on an instance of MyInterface, but it would fail on a call to ImpClass3 trying to handle some="value",  as that class is more restrictive in arguments. Mypy is correct in calling this an error.
